# How can I set the height of element to the actual required height of an HTML element, as opposed to auto in CSS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I'm using `height: auto;` while using `grid` in CSS, the height of the element is set to the maximum height of an element in that row, so, if an element is really small, the length of the `card` div it is in will be increased, but that part will be empty. I want to bypass that behaviour and somehow set the height of the element to the  actual height of the element if the height was only as big as the elements inside it using Javascript. How can I do this?

NOTE: If you have an idea of an approach that might be better than mine, you are welcome to share it. I do not know whether what I am doing is the best approach, so you can recommend other ways to do this (if it is within the confines of HTML, CSS, and Javascript)

**EDIT**:
@SebastianSimon posted this in the comments of this question: `height: min-content`. This worked, only now there is a gap in my grid row because one element in that row is really long, so now there's a gaping hole there and nothing seems to want to come and fill that space...

Comment: [`height: min-content;`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/height#values)?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Awesome, that worked! But now there is a gap in the middle because on element is overly long because of a lot of content. I thought something else might come and fill the gap there. What can I do?

Comment: It sounds like you need a [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) instead of a grid ..?

Comment: A simple search of `css height` in your favorite web browser would give you MDN website and all relevant potential rules in CSS that can be applied with a break down of their definitions.

Comment: Hmm, I know that @dalelandry, but none of the stuff I searched for told me how to solve *this* (maybe my searches are bad, idk)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height did you look on this site here?

Comment: Yes, I had indeed tried Sebastian's answer before asking the question

Comment: Anyway, I'm trying to move to flexbox now, maybe that'll solve it up and I can have a cuppa tea at last

Comment: @Teemu no... the gap between the element below the small one and the small one still exists...

Comment: Flexbox is a large layout system, you probably didn't learn it thoroughly within a quarter.

Comment: @Teemu Sorry if I made myself unclear, but I really need to do this quickly as I'm working for a website, and if you know of any sorta feature of flex that I could use, now'd be grate time to mention it

Comment: And BTW, I know most of flex except a few bits and pieces here and there, but I usually use `flex-direction`, `justify-content` and `align-items`, but I'm not able to find this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I think you need a masonry-layout:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');

(function(container) {
  let html = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
    const h = 50 + 10 * i;
    html += `
      <div style="height: ${ h }px;line-height: ${ h }px">${i}</div>
    `
  }
  container.innerHTML = html
})(container);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.masonry-with-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 1000px;
}

.masonry-with-flex div {
  width: 150px;
  background: #EC985A;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="masonry-with-flex"></div>
```

More solutions [here](https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/)

---

#### EDIT

Another approach could be:

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

(function() {
  cards.forEach((card, i) => {
    card.style.height = 50 + i * 10 + "px"
  })
})();
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.3);  
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div id="app" class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">A</div>
    <div class="card">D</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">B</div>
    <div class="card">E</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">C</div>
    <div class="card">F</div>
  </div>
</div>
```